# What type of collection should I use? delphi

Tags: delphi, key, tdictionary

I want to use one keys for two values in Delphi some thing like this

```
TDictionary<tkey, tfirstvalue,tsecondvalue>;
```

Comment: What's stopping you from using a Tuple as key?

Comment: is used in c# netfram 4 but I want in delphi

Comment: What about using a dynarray as value for the key? Or a record with two values? Then it becomes someting like `TDictionary<TKey, TRecordContainingFirstAndSecondValue>`, which should be doable. or use a `TPair<TFirstValue, TSecondValue>` as value type (which amounts to the 2 type record anyway).

Comment: @DavidStockinger: Delphi does not have built-in tuples. They can easily be emulated using other available data types, but they don't exist as built-in types.

Comment: In other words, the values can easily be combined as one single type (containing several values), in several ways. The TValue part can be as large as you need, so you can have 1:1 and 1:many relations. It only gets hairy if you want to have different key types, or multiple keys per value (many:many), or some such, because TDictionary is not made for that.

Answer (score 2):

Put your values into a compound structure like a record. Then use that record type as your dictionary value type.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi has not Tuple type.
I don't know your purpose but may dynamic array of record type help.

```
Type
Tdict_ = reocord
 tkey:integer;
tfirstvalue,Tsecondvalue :string;
end;
var
Tdict:array of tdict_
...
procedure adddata(Tkey:integer;tfirstvalue:string;Tsecondvalue :string); 
begin
     setlength(tdict,length(tdict)+1);
    tdict[length(tdict)-1].tkey:=tkey;
    tdict[length(tdict)-1].tfirstvalue:=tfirstvalue;
    tdict[length(tdict)-1].tsecondtvalue:=tsecondvalue;    
end;
```

but you must write your own "find" function for return index of array .

for example

```
    Function find(tkey:integer):integer;
    var i:Integer;
    begin
     for i:=0 to length(Tdict)-1 do
     if tdict[i].tkey=i then
       begin
        result:=i;
        break;
       end;
    end;

    Function deletecalue(tkey:integer):integer;
    var i,j:Integer;
    begin
     i:=find(tkey)
        for j:=i to length(Tdict)-2 do
           tdict[j]:=tdict[j+1];
        setlength(tdict,length(tdict)-1);

    end;
```

if keys are strings type must be changed, but it will be slow for huge date .

Also read This:
https://github.com/malcolmgroves/generics.tuples

Answer (score 0):

`TDictionary<TKey, TPair<TFirstValue, TSecondValue>>`, as *@RudyVelthuis* commented, is possible and works. However, `TPair` (found in *System.Generics.Collections*) is not meant for that - the two values are named **Key** and **Value**, which doesn't make sense here. We should make a copy of `TPair`, which could be named `TTuple`.

You can then do `MyDictionary.Add('key', TTuple<string, string>.Create('firstvalue', 'secondvalue'));`

Since it is implemented as a `record` (*value type*), there is no need to free it.